# What happens if my IExceptionPublisher throws an Exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm using the [.NET Exception Management Application Block (EMAB).](https://web.archive.org/web/20100904073630/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=8CA8EB6E-6F4A-43DF-ADEB-8F22CA173E02)

As part of this I am implementing IExceptionPublisher classes.

However, I am wondering what happens if these publishers encounter an Exception.

I had a bit of a look around and [apparently](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424022923/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamga/archive/2004/03/08/86245.aspx) they are meant to do something like this:

```
try 
{
    /* Normal Exception Publishing */
}
catch
{
    ExceptionManager.PublishInternalException(exception, additionalInfo);
}
```

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424022923/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamga/archive/2004/03/08/86245.aspx):

> One caveat: what happens if there is
> an exception in our custom publisher
> code, preventing the publishing to
> MSMQ? For that, we turn to the
> ExceptionManager.PublishInternalException
> method, which will publish the
> exception to the default publisher,
> which is the Windows application event
> log.

However, PublishInternalException is both protected *and* internal so I would have to be implementing ExceptionManager, not IExceptionPublisher, to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It handles itself, publishing both the original Exception and the Exception your IExceptionPublisher threw to the Application Log**

The idea to manually call PublishInternalException must have been related to an early beta. The current ExceptionManager wraps the IExceptionPublisher calls in its own try-catch which calls PublishInternalException itself. If you check out the code in Reflector it basically does this:

```
/* Foreach publisher */
Exception originalException;
try
{
    PublishToCustomPublisher(originalException, additionalInfo, current);
}
catch (Exception publisherException)
{
    /* Both of these calls use the DefaultPublisher which is the Application Log */
    PublishInternalException(publisherException, null);
    PublishToDefaultPublisher(originalException, additionalInfo);
}
```

You may also want to check out the newer [Enterprise Library Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954830)